# Form field with decimal value shows as empty in $_POST

Tags: php, html

I have a form field that looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="last_amount_paid" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>">
```

`$amount` is set to 100.00 and shows up fine if I change the form field from hidden to text.

`$_POST['last_amount_paid ']` is empty when I try and retrieve the value after submit.

I ran `var_dump($_POST)`; and it's showing up as a string and empty

```
["last_amount_paid"]=> string(0) ""
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we please see the form as a whole?

Comment: If you inspect the generated HTML of your form, do you indeed see that `$amount` is being filled in correctly? That is, do you see `value="100.00"` in the source code?

Comment: can you post how you generate the form with all the data, maybe you placed the hidden text after you closed the </form> tag

Answer (score 2):

This should be working:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["last_amount_paid"]))
{
    echo $_POST["last_amount_paid"];
} else
{
    $amount = 100.00;
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="last_amount_paid" value="<?=$amount; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```